# Newline(%n) pattern for Log4j in Linux

Tags: java, linux, servlets, web-applications, log4j

I need a help to break the line and append the logs in new line in Java Web Application.

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %msg%n%n"/>
```

This is the pattern I used. I want to execute this in a Linux environment and `%n` is not working instead logs are appended to the last line only

Comment: What version are you using? In my log4j2.xml, I used your pattern on my linux environment and it is printing logs on newline. Infact you have put `%n%n` so two newlines are being added. The only warning I am getting is due to the Date format you are using. Try using `status="warn"` in your log4j2.xml configuration.

Comment: I mention the Configuration status as all

`status="ALL"`

will it affect anyway ?

Comment: The status is just to see the log messages when the log4j config is loaded so that you get to see if there are any errors in your config. When you say "All" it logs every level log while loading the log4j config. It is better to put the status as `warn` or `debug` otherwise you will end up getting too many log messages. Can you post the output you are getting? Also the complete log4j config.

Comment: Thank for the help @MrunalPagnis . I check with status modification

Comment: Just a thought: are you viewing the log file on Linux or on Windows? If the log file is written by Linux and viewed on Windows, the new line character will not create a new line on Windows, so all your logs will be on the same line

Comment: Yes!! Same case here. I hosted the application in the Linux and view in windows. I find some alternative, put `\r\n` in java log function and it is working now, not altered PatternLayout string.

Thanks @xav

Comment: You're welcome. You could also use another text editor in Windows (e.g. Notepad++) that handles Linux line separator (`\n`).

Comment: @Bhat If you think the answer I gave below helped you, please mark it as "accepted" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that other people know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you viewing the log file on Linux or on Windows? If the log file is written by Linux and viewed on Windows, the new line character will not create a new line on Windows using classical text editors, so all your logs will be on the same line.

You can either use `\r\n` in your Pattern instead of `\n`, or use another text editor in Windows (e.g. Notepad++) that handles Linux line separator (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

I retain the pattern string for log as

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%msg"/>
```

and modified the LogManagement.java

```
private static final Logger LOGGER_OBJECT = LogManager.getLogger(LogManagement.class);

private static final String STRING_DATE_FORMAT = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"; //Date & Time format
private static final SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = new SimpleDateFormat(STRING_DATE_FORMAT); //Simple format conversion
```

code at info function

```
LOGGER_OBJECT.info("\r\n"); //New Line
LOGGER_OBJECT.info("Log Type\t: INFO"); //Log Type
LOGGER_OBJECT.info("\r\n");
LOGGER_OBJECT.info("Date & Time\t: "+SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN.format(new Date()));//Current Date & Time
LOGGER_OBJECT.info("\r\n");
```

This works fine when I log the data in Linux and view in Windows platform